# Sin City Post Processing Effect

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I am trying to make a shader where first I make everything grayscale, then I want to pull out colors based on a Min/Max RGB range. I feel that my `if` statements are not correct. I am trying to get that **Sin City** effect, but what I have isn't working...

```
CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert_img
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
uniform float4 _ColorMin;
uniform float4 _ColorMax;
uniform sampler2D _RampTex;

fixed4 frag (v2f_img i) : COLOR {
    fixed4 original = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
    fixed grayscale = Luminance(original.rgb);
    half2 remap = half2(grayscale, 0.5);
    fixed4 output = tex2D(_RampTex, remap);

    half avg = (original.r + original.g + original.b) / 3;
    half4 nC = half4(avg, avg, avg, original.a);

    if(original.r >= _ColorMin.r && original.r <= _ColorMax.r){
        nC.r = original.r;
    }
    if(original.g >= _ColorMin.g && original.g <= _ColorMax.g){
        nC.g = original.g;
    }
    if(original.b >= _ColorMin.b && original.b <= _ColorMax.b){
        nC.b = original.b;
    }

    output = fixed4(nC.r, nC.g, nC.b, original.a);
    return output;
}
ENDCG
```

Here are the results I get when I say I wan't

0 - 1 Red
0 - 0 Green
0 - 0 Blue

[image: Full Red]

Here is the original:

[image: Original]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
fixed4 original = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
half avg = (original.r + original.g + original.b) / 3;
half4 gray = half4(avg, avg, avg, original.a);      
half4 nC = gray;
if (original.r >= _ColorMin.r && original.r <= _ColorMax.r)
{
    if (original.g >= _ColorMin.g && original.g <= _ColorMax.g)
    {
        if (original.b >= _ColorMin.b && original.b <= _ColorMax.b)
        {
            nC = original;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    nC = gray;
}


output = fixed4(nC.r, nC.g, nC.b, original.a);
return output;
```

This will give you abrupt outlines where the condition isn't met. To combat that you could blend the color in the `else` block.

Comment: I found a way that works fairly, what I do is find the hue of the two colors then match them together. to see if they are the same hue